# I need someone who can execute my query on mysql please. I am looking for the mistake I made so far

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DATABASE Scenario2;

USE Scenario2;

CREATE TABLE Project
(
    Project_Code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, 
    Project_Name VARCHAR(30), 
    Project_Manager VARCHAR(30), 
    Project_Budget NUMERIC(9,2),
    Project_Departement_ID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (Project_Departement_ID) 
         REFERENCES Departement(Project_Departement_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Departement
(
    Project_Departement_ID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    Departement_No VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Departement_Name VARCHAR(30), 
    HOURLY_RATE DECIMAL(5,2),
    Employee_No VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Employee_No) 
        REFERENCES Employee(Employee_No)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Employee_No VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    Employee_Name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Comment: Yep, the order of table creation is exactly back-to-front

Comment: Incidentally, FWIW (probably not much), I think the ids governing internal relationships should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any error? The only issue I can see is sequence of tables creation. Since the table created first is dependent on 2nd table and 2nd Table is dependent on 3rd Table. So, it should be something like this. Please share the error you are getting in your script.

```
CREATE DATABASE Scenario2; 
use Scenario2; 
CREATE TABLE Employee    (
    Employee_No            VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, 
    Employee_Name          VARCHAR(30)
);
CREATE TABLE Departement (
    Project_Departement_ID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL unique PRIMARY KEY, 
    Departement_No         VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    Departement_Name       VARCHAR(30), 
    HOURLY_RATE            DECIMAL(5,2), 
    Employee_No            VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    constraint foreign key(Employee_No) references Employee(Employee_No)
); 
CREATE TABLE Project     (
    Project_Code           VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL unique PRIMARY KEY, 
    Project_Name           VARCHAR(30), 
    Project_Manager        VARCHAR(30), 
    Project_Budget         NUMERIC(9,2), 
    Project_Departement_ID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    constraint foreign key(Project_Departement_ID) references Departement(Project_Departement_ID)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Amit! Your answer was very helpful.